# set contains duplicate objectid in js

Tags: javascript, mongodb

solvedby is an array containing object id, (It should contain only distinct value. - this is what the target is.)

```
const whosolved = new Set(problem.solvedby);
            whosolved.add(job.userId);
            
            problem.solvedby =  Array.from(whosolved);
            console.log("...",whosolved);
            await problem.save();
```

but this code contains duplicate  after console log i got

```
... Set(3) {
  new ObjectId("642832de152a5463a43878d2"),
  new ObjectId("64383c8a5384e6f95253dc0a"),
  new ObjectId("64383c8a5384e6f95253dc0a")
}
```

Here the last 2 values, that I pushed was from same user. The set contains duplicate value as can be seen from above result.
Although I expected it to contain only distinct value.

Comment: @TimRoberts I want distinct value but it has duplicates in it , according to me set in js contains distinct value.

Comment: ObjectId is type object, objects are unique by reference. if you want unique then create it using a set of string ids first then convert it to ObjectId

Comment: So,`job.userId` is an object, and not just a string?  If you create a new object each time, even if it has the same string, it will be seen as two different objects.